# what is better to achieve the below - poll, inotify or anything else

Tags: c, linux, polling, inotify

Suppose the below code is invoked in a pthread that waits to read input from device, but the device itself is not available initially during the startup and is plugged in later through a usb port [say a keyboard].

Is there a better way to wait than using `do..while` ? I see with `do..while` the CPU utilization is high until the file descriptor is acquired.

```
#define DEV "/dev/input/event2"

int fd; 
fd = open(DEV, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s.\n", dev, strerror(errno));
    //return EXIT_FAILURE;
    do{     
        fd = open(dev, O_RDONLY);
    }       
    while(fd < 0);
}

while (1)
{
    //Logic to read from say keyboard device
}
```

Comment: You should really check *what* error `open` have. It might be something that isn't really recoverable.

Comment: At very least, you should sleep for some short interval to prevent overly high CPU usage (not memory).

Comment: @Aconcagua, thank you for correcting me. Also lil curious to know what happens behind the scene with the sleep in place.Any pointer to it is appreciated.

Comment: @shwink *Roughly* described: Having more threads than CPU cores the threads need share the cores, of course. So the OS switches between them, assigning each of them a certain amount of time it can use a specific CPU, then lets the other threads run again, while the previous one has to wait until it is its turn again. This is called scheduling. A sleeping thread simply is not considered for scheduling until the sleeping time has elapsed... Thus a sleeing thread does not consume CPU resources either (other than the scheduler checking if it is available again).

Answer (score 2):

you can use notification feature of libudev:

http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/libudev.html

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use inotify as:

Create inotify object: 
    fd=inotify_init();

Add your path in watcher list:
    inotify_add_watch(fd,<YOUR_PATH>, IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE)<0)

Continuously watch in infinite loop and use select for timeout and wait  for event  on fd.
    ret = pselect(fd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv, NULL);

When the event will occur, read the event.
    rsize = read(fd, buf, BUF_LEN);
    event=(struct inotify_event *)buf;

Check for event:
if((event->mask & IN_CREATE)){
    //USB added
}else if((event->mask & IN_DELETE)){
    //USB deleted
}
```

I hope this helped.